# npm-run-all failing when running a "tsc-watch" command in parallel

Tags: node.js, tsc, npm-scripts

I am trying to use `npm-run-all` to manage running two servers at the same time. For one of the servers, I am trying to run it in a `watch` mode using `tsc-watch`.

The command looks like such:

```
"start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node dist/server.js\""
```

`npm-run-all` starts up both of the servers successfully. `tsc-watch` also watches the Typescript file for changes and automatically recompiles it successfully.

However, when `tsc-watch` recompiles the Typescript file and restarts the server, it seems like `npm-run-all` stops working properly. Specifically, if I try to kill both of the servers by pressing `CTRL + C` in the terminal (OSX), it will only kill the server that `tsc-watch` recompiled while the other server remains running.

I'm thinking that there must be a way to fix this. Anyone have some tips for me?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. I think this is just a bug with `npm-run-all`. Using `concurrently` instead doesn't experience this issue (kills both servers when hitting `CTRL-C`).